# I need to get a list of all domains registered in a specific country

Tags: dns, domainservices

I need to get a list of all domains registered in a specific country

like all domain has same domain extension example :

domains of Saudia Arabia  usually end with :

```
.sa
.com.sa
.gov.sa
.edu.sa
.org.sa
```

so is there any way to get domain list for one country ?

i tried to use google like search :
site.*.sa
i show me only 28 page with 10 results per page = 280 total 
it is not enough result !

Answer (score 0):

Most ccTLDs don't publish the entire zonefile, for very good reasons.

So short answer: you probably can't